# Datalist not working in one specific input field

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

So I've been designing an HTML+Bootstrap form. I want the ***Productor*** field to allow free-writing, but it should show existing DB records as possible values (which is why I use a datalist and <option> tags). The list values are echoed from a PHP script (temporary solution while I learn proper AJAX).

For some reason, the ***list*** attribute works on any field except for the two fields within the ***input group***s. Thus, I'm pretty sure the list works correctly, and I have checked that the values are reaching my browser. However, when giving the ***list*** attribute to the fields ***Productor*** or ***Campo***, the list does not appear as I type or click on the input fieds.

Here is the form code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card shadow-sm rounded-left-edge">
        <div class="card-body mx-2">
            <!--Form start-->
            <form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"
                name="fdeclaracion" method="post" ,target="_blank">
                <!--productor-->
                <div class="row mt-2">
                    <label for="productor" class="form-label mb-0">Nombre del Productor:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input list="productores_dropdown_2" required class="form-control" name="productor" id="productor">
                        <datalist id="productores_dropdown_2">
                            <?php include "../dropdown/productores_dropdown.php" ?>
                        </datalist>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#productorModal">
                            Crear...
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--campo-->
                <div class="row mt-2">
                    <label for="campo" class="form-label mb-0">Nombre del Campo:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo" id="campo" required>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#campoModal">
                            Crear...
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <!--areaNoIntacta-->
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="areaNoIntacta" class="form-label mb-0 px-0 pt-2 pb-1">Área decl. no intacta (has):
                        </label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="areaNoIntacta" id="areaNoIntacta" required>
                    </div>
                   
                    <!--areaXTend-->
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="areaXTend" class="form-label mb-0 px-0 pt-2 pb-1">Área decl. XTEND (has):</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="areaXTend" id="areaXTend" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Submit-->
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col text-end px-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, this works as intended for the other input fields, just not for the ones I want it to.